# UIAlertView with NO buttons and how to close it

Tags: iphone, xcode, uialertview

I have activity indicator in alert view that I use until my app gets the server response. The app send data to server and the alert view shows, how to close it when the server sends me the response. Here is code from my alert

```
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Canceling reservation" message:@"please wait" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];

        UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

        // Adjust the indicator to place at the bottom of the dialog window.
        indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2, alert.bounds.size.height-50);
        [indicator startAnimating];
        [alert addSubview:indicator];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD) instead of standart UIAlertView for something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:` delegate method for dismissing the alertView.

```
[alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
```

Make sure that `alert` is declared on the `@Interface`.

> **dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:**
>
> Dismisses the receiver, optionally with animation.
>
> `- (void)dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex animated:(BOOL)animated Parameters`
>
> **buttonIndex**
>
> ```
> The index of the button that was clicked just before invoking this method. The button indices start at 0.
> ```
>
> **animated**
>
> ```
> YES if the receiver should be removed by animating it first; otherwise, NO if it should be removed immediately with no animation.
> ```
>
> Discussion
>
> In iOS 4.0, you may want to call this method whenever your application
>   moves to the background. An alert view is not dismissed automatically
>   when an application moves to the background. This behavior differs
>   from previous versions of the operating system, where they were
>   canceled automatically when the application was terminated. Dismissing
>   the alert view gives your application a chance to save changes or
>   abort the operation and perform any necessary cleanup in case your
>   application is terminated later. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In UIAlertView.h

Please refer [UIAlertView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html)